# Persist value across multiple views in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have multiple tabs in an MVC page. Each tab is a seperate view aspx with same controller. I have a common master page.

On saving the data on 1st tab I get an `ID` which I want to use in other tabs of the page.

User can click any tab after saving data in 1st tab.

Currently I am using `TempData` to persist `ID` across tabs. I want to persist data without using `TempData` or `cookies`.

Is it possible to persist value in master page? Is there any other approach better than this?

> Note: We have load balancer for the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend ViewData rather than TempData as TempData disappears the first time it is used.

Based on your question though, I assume if you don't like TempData, than ViewData won't be what you're looking for anyway, but I do think it's the best solution for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Create one page with several tabs on it, visible part you can manage by jquery tab plugin (eg. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), you won't need to persist it on server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this id as a part of your model, you can include it into the other view's routes like `../tab/<Your_Id>/`. You would not have to persist its value in ViewData or Session or Cookie.